# Why Remove Kedusha via Pidyon Haben?

Tags: sources-mekorot, kedusha-holiness, shehecheyanu, pidyon-haben

Rav Noach Isaac Oelbaum [quotes](https://torahanytime.com/lectures/54336) the Shevet Sofer who explains the reason why the father says the beracha Shehechiyanu for removing his firstborn son's kedusha via Pidyon Haben, which would not seem to be a particularly happy event, is because divinely gifted holiness is nothing to be proud of, rather having that kedusha removed and working hard to reattain it is the true happiness.

Where is this Shevet Sofer (or commentator who says something similar)?